# Can't install BI Publisher for desktop

Tags: oracle11g, failed-installation, bi-publisher

I'm having problems installing BI Publisher for Desktop 11.1.1.9.0 32bit(11g) on Win7 64 bit system (Office 2013). Previously I successfully installed it but there was no add-on visible in Office, so tried with 64 bit version but with no luck. After that I've uninstalled it but now it keeps giving me these errors, "INSTALL DIR get falied!" and "TBMenusSetup.msi!"

Any idea hoe to solve this?

Br

Comment: What version is your Office? 32-bit/64-bit? I have Office 2013-32bit and Win764bit, working fine

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did on Windows 7 (64-bit) and Office 2013 (32-bit):

1. Download: Oracle BI Publisher Desktop 11.1.1.7.0 for 32 bit Office on Windows (244 MB)  - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/downloads/index.html
2. Run BIPublisherDesktop32.exe
3. If Add-In doesn't show up at this point, run step 4
4. Run setup.exe from here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\setup.exe
5. Done

Answer (score 0):

I also check the following conditions if I have trouble with installing BIP (which I often have)

1. Make sure that the versions on your system are matching
   (JRE,Office,BIP). That means: If you have Office in 64bit you need
   JRE(64bit) and BIP(64bit).
2. Check if the addon is deactivated by word and activate it in case.
3. Use "Run as Administrator" with the BIP Installer.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

download bi publisher desktop and do a fresh install.
if you are not getting the add on then go to Microsoft office icon-->word option-->add ins-->then check in manage drop down(disabled items).If its Bi Publisher then click on that.You will get this in MS word.

Answer (score -2):

https://carsandcode.com/2014/05/12/oracle-bi-publisher-desktop-on-64-bit-windows-with-32-bit-office/
Personally, until next time, not sure what worked, as above step I did earlier with no resolution.
But, I have been installing, troubleshooting BIP Desktop for few years and each time it is broken, fix do not exist and there are threads which leads to absolutely nothing. This time around, O365 was rolled out to Pilot Users and yes BIP toolbar gone. Uninstalled O365, re-installed Office 2010, repair/remove/reinstall - none worked. Ran MS Debug/ Sysinternals - Procmon/ProcessXP - found leak threads but nothing to suggest which components is missing or corrupted. Finally, I started running all msi and pre-req sw in BIP dir and DotNetInstallFiles, and it did come back the elusive toolbar, which MS Word fails to load or kept in Inactive add-ins.